# JDatabaseQuery quote correctly the items into select

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdatabase

I have written a database query, like so:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("u.*,ju.username,ju.email,ju.lastvisitDate as last_login")
    ->from("#__component_users AS u")
    ->leftJoin("#__users AS ju ON ju.id = u.uid");
```

How can I quote items in `select` clause, especially when there is an alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$db->quoteName(mixed $name, mixed $as = null)
```

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_quoteName

With the quoteName-function you can quote column names. It accepts strings and arrays. A simple quote with alias (the AS) would look like:

```
$db->quoteName('ju.lastvisitDate', 'last_login')
```

$as (the second parameter) is always optional. So if you don't want to give your column an alias just write

```
$db->quoteName('ju.lastvisitDate')
```

With an array it would like this:

```
$db->quoteName(array('ju.email', 'ju.lastvisitDate'), array(null, 'last_login'))
```

Note the null value in the second array if you don't want to give a column an alias.

As long as you don't use any reserved keywords or variables (e.g. submitted by the user) as column names I would not escape them. See also this:
https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#Secure_field_names

Comment: @user3533235 this is a clear, correct, and comprehensive answer.  Unless you require further explanation about something, please award the green tick to this answer so that this page is deemed resolved.

Comment: @user3533235 Please accept this answer.